# Loop through json array, check checkbox where checkbox value matches json value

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I am rendering a list of items from my db to the view so the user can select some.  In the case there are already selected and the user has come back to this view, I need to check for selected items and mark them accordingly.  In my MVC controller I get the previously selected items from the db and pass with the model as a json string:

```
   ViewBag.selectedSoftware = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selected);
```

I then need to loop through this list and compare to all the checkbox values on the page.  If there is a match, I want the checkbox checked.

This is the closest I have gotten (meaning it didn't throw an error):

```
    $(function () {
        var softwareList = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.selectedSoftware);

        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
            if (this.value == softwareList.SoftwareId) {
                this.prop('checked', true);
            }
        })
    })
```

This is a checkbox in the view:

```
      <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedSoftwareList" value="@item.SoftwareId" />
```

Comment: What does data look like? Presumably there is a relationship between input name and data array objects?

Answer (score 0):

assuming that My Object == Your JSON, and Your Data == My ID

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var fruits = {
     fruit1: "Kiwi",
     fruit2: "Apple",
     fruit3: "Apricot",
     fruit4: "Orange",
     fruit5: "Banana",
     fruit6: "Avocado",
     fruit7: "Cherry",
     fruit8: "Strawberry",
     fruit9: "Guava",
     fruit9: "Mango",
     fruit10: "Lemon"
   };

   for (item in fruits) {
     switch (fruits[item]) {
       case 'Apple':
         $("#Apple").prop({
           "checked": true
         });
         break;

       case 'Orange':
         $("#Orange").prop({
           "checked": true
         });
         break;

       case 'Grapes':
         $("#Grapes").prop({
           "checked": true
         });
         break;

       case 'Strawberry':
         $("#Strawberry").prop({
           "checked": true
         });
         break;

       case 'Mango':
         $("#Mango").prop({
           "checked": true
         });
         break;

       default:
         break;
     }
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' id='Apple' />
<label>Apple</label>
<br />
<input type='checkbox' id='Orange' />
<label>Orange</label>
<br />
<input type='checkbox' id='Grapes' />
<label>Grapes</label>
<br />
<input type='checkbox' id='Strawberry' />
<label>Strawberry</label>
<br />
<input type='checkbox' id='Mango' />
<label>Mango</label>
```